# What is the most widely-used Javascript graphics library that is the most cross-browser compatible?

Tags: javascript, graphics

I know there are tons of great graphics libraries for javascript...

Now, I know that there are other questions asking for graphics library suggestions. But none of them address the following issues:

1. What is the most widely-used javascript-graphics library right now?
2. Can it handle text, rotation, arcs, bezier-style line geometries, and is compatible with at least FF, IE(7/8), Safari, and Chrome...
3. Also, because of my client's fears of required plug-ins that users need to add to their browser, it needs to be something that can load on-the-fly and not require the user to permanently install anything external.

Does such an animal exist?

I am looking for your experienced opinion on this one.

Comment: @LarsH, I know. That is why I asked. I am having a really tough time deciding on which library to go with. I am in a situation where I was when I had to decide between jQuery and Scriptaculous... I originally went with Scriptaculous, but ended up switching due to unforeseen needs that Scriptaculous did not adequately address...

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the hardest problems in software development: picking the right framework(s) to invest time in to learn if they'll do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

For cross platform support I generally find I can trust [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to do the job.

Comment: Does it play well with FireFox, IE7/8, Safari, and Chrome? As well as the iPad thingymajig?

Comment: The website claims: `Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+`. Yes, IE6! which I've personally tested. Don't know about iPad but i should since it works fine in Safari.

Comment: OK, apparently it works very well on the iPad: http://thechangelog.com/post/586893430/rapha-l-js-1-4-now-with-touch-support-ipad

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at processingjs first.
http://processingjs.org/

Comment: It looks good, but how portable is it? I can't find anything on the processing.js web site that says what browsers it runs on. Does it require HTML 5?

Comment: I fiddled with processing.js last night... Considerations: (a) it seems to take a long time to start up, even for small demos (possibly the cost of translating Processing to JS); (b) factor in the cost of learning the details of a new language, which is sort of a java dialect with its own graphics API.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the html5 `<canvas/>` element with the 2d graphics API.

Although the canvas element isn't supported in IE, you can make it work with excanvas.js from  http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/.

Explorer canvas is a simple javascript include that emulates canvas element support using vector graphics. On the other browsers, you will have canvas support.

I used this approach to make a realtime scrolling trend control that worked across browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I neglected to mention that I also need to hold off on moving towards HTML5 for now. Most of my clients are not willing to embark on the newer technologies until support for the current, most widely used technologies' support has eroding to the point that upgrading is compulsory... So, I have to stay away from bleeding-edge, cutting-edge, and leading-edge technologies. :-(